# Jquery .append places ending </div> wrong

Tags: jquery, append

Im currently appending the following:

```
$('.fbResults').append("<div class='fbItem'>");
$('.fbResults').append("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='imagePreloader' />");
$('.fbResults').append("<img src='"+imgUrl+"' class='img-polaroid' />");
$('.fbResults').append("<span class='fbNames'>Name</span>");
$('.fbResults').append("</div>");
```

My issue is that the ending `</div>` seems to be placed just after the starting .fbItem and not in the ending order as I want it to appear.

The html result from the above append:

```
<div class="fbItem"></div>
<img alt="Friends loading" class="imagePreloader" src="images/ajax-loader.gif">
<img class="img-polaroid" src="image">
<span class="fbNames">Name</span>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to append to the `.fbItem` and not to `.fbResults`.

Comment: And also the ending div is unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this `.append("<div class='fbItem'>");`

jquery automatically append a closing tag `</div>`

Demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/uVcrn/

You can get around it like this -

```
$('.fbResults').append($("<div class='fbItem'>")
.append("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='imagePreloader' />")
.append("<img src='"+imgUrl+"' class='img-polaroid' />")
.append("<span class='fbNames'>Name</span>"));
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/uVcrn/2/

Comment: Not sure which of the posted responses would be the most correct one, however I found this one straightforward to use and ended up doing this.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.append()` it adds the new element, including its closing tag, so you're just appending each element one after the other.

You'd be better off calling `append()` once, passing the entire html as a string:

```
.append("<div class='fbItem'>"
        + "<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='imagePreloader' />" 
        + "<img src='" + imgUrl + "' class='img-polaroid' />" 
        + "<span class='fbNames'>Name</span>" +
        "</div>");
```

Comment: like this approach, will also try this out

Answer (score 1):

You are appending all content to single div. Append '.fbItem' div to '.fbResults' div and then all other contents to '.fbItem' div. When you append div to other div without closing tag it automatically close the div no need to add separate closing tag to it.

Your code goes like this:

```
jQuery('.fbResults').append("< div class='fbItem'">);

jQuery('.fbItem').append("< img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='imagePreloader' />");
jQuery('.fbItem').append("< img src='"+imgUrl+"' class='img-polaroid' />");
jQuery('.fbItem').append("< span class='fbNames'>Name</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the elemtns inside your div because in your system you append after the div and not inside the div
Try this:

```
   $('.fbResults').append("<div class='fbItem'>");
   $('.fbItem').append("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='imagePreloader' />");
   $('.fbItem').append("<img src='"+imgUrl+"' class='img-polaroid' />");
   $('.fbItem').append("<span class='fbNames'>Name</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as it should be.
When creating new elements through jQuery, it'll automatically close the tags.

Either add this content as text, or create a variable out of the fbItem div, and append the other elements to that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using correctly `append` method. Try with this

```
var div = [];
div.push("<div class='fbItem'>");
div.push("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' class='imagePreloader' />");
div.push("<img src='"+imgUrl+"' class='img-polaroid' />");
div.push("<span class='fbNames'>Name</span>");
div.push("</div>");
$('.fbResults').append(div.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.fbItem').append("<div class='fbResults'>");` please change all like this and try

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to make sure you append the newly created items correctly:

```
// Create all the dynamic elements
var $div = $("<div/>",{class:'fbItem'});
var $img1 = $("<img>", {src:'images/ajax-loader.gif', class:'imagePreloader'});
var $img2 = $("<img>", {src:imgUrl, class:'img-polaroid'});
var $span =  $("<span/>",{class:'fbNames', text:'Name'});

// Append the two images and the span to the dynamic div
$div.append($img1).append($img2).append($span);

// Finally append the div to 'fbResults'
$('.fbResults').append($div);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y2kYB/)